# PHP trying to send separate date and time variables to sql

Tags: php, sql, date, time, formatting

I'm trying to send two separate variables to a mysql database, one for date, and one for time.  At the moment, both of these variables are strings, and the mysql columns are formatted as types date and time.  What should i send the variables over as in my sql query?

**EDIT: added the error**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (jk497.Booking,
>   CONSTRAINT Booking_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (PerfDate, PerfTime) REFERENCES
>   Performance (PerfDate, PerfTime))' in
>   /home/cuc/jk497/public_html/bookingReceipt.php on line 58

**my code**

```
$time = "17:00:00"; 
$sql = "insert into Booking values (':id', ':date', ':time', ':fullName', ':email', ':rowNum', ':numSeats', ':bookedSeats');"; 
$handle = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$handle->execute(array(':id' => $_SESSION['id'], ':date' => $SESSION['date'], ':time' => $time, ':fullName' => $_SESSION['fullName'], ':email' => $_SESSION['email'], ':rowNum' => $seatIndex, ':numSeats' => $_SESSION['numSeats'], ':bookedSeats' => $_SESSION['bookedSeats']));
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? It good to add some code and errors you have and what you expect. read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see how to improve your question.

Comment: Glavic, i tried passing them in as a string and the sql database reects it :(

Comment: @davejal

the error message i get from sql is as follows:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`jk497`.`Booking`, CONSTRAINT `Booking_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PerfDate`, `PerfTime`) REFERENCES `Performance` (`PerfDate`, `PerfTime`))' in /home/cuc/jk497/public_html/bookingReceipt.php on line 58

Comment: please add enough of your structure for us to be able to help any further

Comment: @davejal working on it, having difficulty posting the code in a readable way ^^

Comment: check out the edit and accept

Comment: @davejal thanks for that ^^

Comment: I'm not used to the way you created the query, were did you get this code?

Comment: which parts of the query do you mean?

Comment: its all stuff i've either googled, seen on here or been shown as part of my course material (studying a comp sci master's)

Answer (score 0):

From [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) example I would first change the code you have to:

```
$sql = "insert into Booking ('id','date','time','fullName','email','rowNum','numSeats','bookedSeats') values (:id,:date,:time,:fullName,:email,:rowNum,:numSeats,:bookedSeats)"; 
$handle = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$handle->bindParam(':id',$_SESSION['id']);
$handle->bindParam(':date',$SESSION['date']);
$handle->bindParam(':time',$time);
$handle->bindParam(':fullName',$_SESSION['fullName']);
$handle->bindParam(':email',$_SESSION['email']);
$handle->bindParam(':rowNum',$seatIndex);
$handle->bindParam(':numSeats',$_SESSION['numSeats']);
$handle->bindParam(':bookedSeats',$_SESSION['bookedSeats']);

$handle->execute();
```

**Things to consider:**

1. Queries have specific order of querying

   ```
   insert into table () values ();
   insert into table values (); //is what you had (this is not correct and will never work afaik)
   ```
2. you are sending the values as an array, not sure why, but you could just send the values

   ```
   bind_param($_SESSION['id'],$SESSION['date'],$time,$_SESSION['fullName'],$_SESSION['email'],$seatIndex,$_SESSION['numSeats'],$_SESSION['bookedSeats'])
   ```

**Working with your query from the beginning**

change:

```
$sql = "insert into Booking values (':id', ':date', ':time', ':fullName', ':email', ':rowNum', ':numSeats', ':bookedSeats');";
```

into

```
$sql = "insert into Booking (id,date,time,fullName,email,rowNum,numSeats, bookedSeats) values (:id,:date,:time,:fullName,:email,:rowNum,:numSeats, :bookedSeats)";
```

Comment: changed to your suggestion, now i get the error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param() in /home/cuc/jk497/public_html/bookingReceipt.php on line 42

Comment: sorry, I was giving you mysqli examples, will change it to pdo in a moment

Comment: go back to what you had in the beginning and change it using my last edit

Comment: I also changed bind_param to bindParam, difference between mysqli and pdo, so now you shouldn't get that error anymore

Comment: based on your suggestion about going back to my original code (and after changing the sql column headers to the actual names) i managed to get it working.  Thanks for your help!